# Add emoji in PHP

Tags: php, utf8mb4

Let me explain my problem.
On my site, currently my emojis are well displayed, however, on the future version I'm developing, there are the "?" problems when I use the same database (with utf8mb4_general_ci).

Is there a PHP alternative to debug this?

Thanks,

Comment: Which character encoding were you using before (same)? What have you changed about the configuration of displaying emojis in your new site?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone no, I already have this

Comment: @AntoniosP. I didn't change anything, and the encoding of the file is in UTF-8 like the other version of my site.

Comment: See "querstion mark" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Comment: Problem solved!
The problem was:
- The connection to my database being in UTF8 and not utf8mb4_unicode_ci